# How to save calendar events based on CalendarView

Tags: java, android, events, calendar

I want to know which would be the best idea for storing event entries "in" the days of the CalendarView. I need ideas of how to insert the events and connect them to the days.

My only idea would be to create a gson (in order to load it when user opens the fragment where the calendar is ) with an arraylist which contains all the days and the respective events entered ( title , date , location, description) but I suppose there could be other ways?

Right now what I did was the following:
- double-tap of the date
- open dialog asking for : title, date, location , description
- save the entries intro a custom class arrayList (but I suppose its hard to have everything into an arrayList afterall .. )

Is there a way to add events in the calendar through the library and the CalendarView object and to have them saved?

Comment: Look into room database. You can keep your data class and just add a few annotations. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: try this.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider